# I got one problem in SQL,i need to get start of next minute value

Tags: t-sql

I need to get the start of next Minute value, that means suppose I got the output for `GETDATE()` is **19.11.2019 12:52:51** but I need to get **19.11.2019 12:53:00**

This is my code:

```sql
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
DECLARE @increase  int = 1;
SELECT DATEADD(mi, @increase,@date) as nextminutedate;
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? What does not work as expected?

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to round the date down.  One method in SQL Server is:

```
select dateadd(minute, 1+datediff(minute, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

This is a little inscrutable.  The `datediff()` calculates the number of minutes from a time of `0` for the current date/time.  The `dateadd()` adds this back in.

Note:  This works for minutes.  You might have overflow problems with seconds or milliseconds.

For this reason, I rather prefer:

```
select dateadd(minute, 1+datediff(minute, '2000-01-01', getdate()), '2000-01-01')
```

I find this is clearer in the intention.